# Mongo for each not doing the funtcion

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create a log document for each task that is late.

```
const dte = new Date();
  Task.find()
    .where("status")
    .ne("Done", "Stuck", "Late")
    .where("date")
    .lt(dte)
    .updateMany({ status: "Late" })
    .map(task => {
      const newLog = new Log({
        message: `${moment(dte).format("LT")}: The task: ${
          department.name
        } is delayed`,
        type: "late"
      });

      newLog.save();
    });
```

I expect to have the logs created at the db, the error message that I got is .map() is not a function.

Comment: updateMany() returns a Promise and a Promise had no map() function. you should do then() after updatedMany().

Comment: I already tried that, it returns: "TypeError: tasks.map is not a function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this.

```
const dte = new Date();
Task.find({
  status: {
  $ne: ["Done", "Stuck", "Late"]
},
 date: {
   $lt: dte
 }
}).then((tasks) => {

   // loop through tasks
   tasks.forEach(async (task) => {
      const newLog = new Log({
        message: `${moment(dte).format("LT")}: The task: ${
        department.name
        } is delayed`,
        type: "late"
      });

      await newLog.save();

      // update task
      task.set({ status: "Late" });
      await task.save();
 });
})
```